# Expecting member declaration even though the val is declared the line above

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, variable-declaration

I looked at all of the other questions about this error, but none of them helped. I am trying to create a reference to a button in my layout file, and when I set the onClickListener, I get "expecting member declaration." This occurs on line 35. Side note, I am also getting the error "Function declaration must have a name" on the same line. Here is the code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*

private var userLocation: Any = ""

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.locations)
        spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.support.v7.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.rooms)
        )
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                adapterView: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                p3: Long
            ) {
                userLocation = adapterView?.getItemAtPosition(position)!!
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }
        }
    }
    val button: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    button.setOnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected $userLocation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines of code:

```
    val button: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    button.setOnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected $userLocation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

you have defined outside any functions. That means `button` is a class-level property you are defining. Properties are initialized before any functions are called, so this `findViewById` call will fail at runtime because it will be called before `onCreate()`.

And you cannot simply call a function like `setOnClickListener` at the the top level of a function in the middle of nowhere. That's why you have the "expecting member declaration" error.

You need to move all of this code inside your `onCreate()` function.